# rename a value in a column according to a condition

Tags: r, replace, rename, r-factor

I would like to change the name of the entries in the columns of a dataframe when the values of one of the columns are 0. I tried this way, but get an error message. Suppose I would like to change the entries of columns 1,2,3 to "A" when the entries of column 3 are 0

```
df[ df[ , 3 ] == 0 , c(1,2,4) ] <- "A"
```

I get

```
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = c("A", "A", "A",  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Comment: That's not an error -- it's a warning message telling you that one of your columns is a factor that doesn't have a level for "A". You may find it easier to store your data as strings instead of factors (e.g. by creating your data with the `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` argument).

Comment: Your right, it's a warning, but the problem is that instead of obtaining "A", I get <NA>.

Comment: @user34771, did you even read what josilber wrote, or you just quit after "That's not an error"? What part of *stringsAsFactors=FALSE argument* didn't you understand? Please read documentation off `?data.frame`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work after following command:

```
df[,c(1,2,4)]=sapply(df[,c(1,2,4)], function(x) as.character(x))
```

Can be shortened to following as suggested by josilber in the comments:

```
df[,c(1,2,4)]=sapply(df[,c(1,2,4)], as.character)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked perfectly. I would really appreciate if you could give me some additional information about changing the data to character.

Comment: ?as.character, ?as.numeric, ?as.factor etc commands will help you. Also you should click on tick to accept / upvote if you find answers helpful.

Comment: sorry I am still a novice. I accepted your very useful answer, but still do not have enough reputation to vote up.

Comment: No worries. Welcome to the forum. Don't get impressed by my answer. You have'nt seen the experts on this forum yet!

Comment: Instead of `function(x) as.character(x)`, you could just pass `as.character` as the second argument.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am editing my answer. Do you see @ user34771 ?